# Solve $(1+1/x)^x=(1+1/a)^a$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve $(1+1/x)^x=(1+1/a)^a$.

Obviously, x = a is a solution. How can I know are there any other solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x$, $a$ is real number such that $a,x\notin (-1,0)$, there is no another solution. Because $f(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{x} \right)^x$ is strictly increasing and $f(x)>e$ if $x<-1$ and $1\le f(x)<e$ if $x\ge 0$.